# Import CSV into existing layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, csv

I have been provided with a number of blank shapefile to use as a schema for Work As Executed data. I have a survey in DWG format, from which I export data as a CSV file.

Is it possible to import this directly into an existing shapefile layer?  I can only see that you can create a new layer, but would like to avoid this step if possible.  Ideally I would be able to map some of the attributes also, but even the geometry would be useful.

[image: Shapefile Schema]

[image: CSV Data]

Comment: Try something like: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131041/is-there-a-qgis-alternative-for-arcmaps-append-to-shapefile-data-management-t/250945 or: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#modifying-vector-layers

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/gacarrillor/AppendFeaturesToLayer

Answer (score 0):

In general, a CSV file consists of **points**. Your example file contains X, Y and Z co-ordinates, and the X and Y co-ordinates look to be in metres [probably]. The key attribute you need to import a csv file into a GIS [I use QGIS] is that there must be an 'X' and a 'Y' column. These could be Universal Transverse Mercator co-ordinates or Ordnance Survey Grid co-ordinates; it depends where you are. Either way, it is quite easy to import these into QGIS; you just have to tell QGIS what kind of co-ordinates they are [UTM Zone 55 South, for example], and that 'Position X' and 'Position Y' are the X and Y co-ordinates. Once you have the file loaded up and displaying, it is very easy to export them as a shapefile, if you need to [in QGIS, right-click and 'Export As'].
If you need lines or polygons from your csv file, it's a bit more complicated. Instead of X and Y, you need a column that contains 'WKT' [Well-Known Text] that describes the shape. This is more complicated, but it can be done.