# Choosing several common attributes in shapefile merge (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, merge

In QGIS 3.16: I have 2 non-overlapping polygon layers that I want to merge to one layer.  The two layers have associated attribute tables with 13 fields in common (same variable, same field type; different names in header however) and additionally, several fields each that are unique to that layer.

What I would like to do is merge the two layers in a way that

1. allows me to choose which *common* attribute fields can get collapsed to the same column (for example: merge field `NUM_SITE` from layer1 to field `_02numsite` from layer2;  merge field `ORGANISME` from layer1 to field `_04organis` from layer2);  and,
2. will add all *non-common* attribute fields to the resulting merged table as well (with Null/empty values for the features originally lacking those attributes).  And obviously,
3. I want to keep associated geometry.

Note: since the two layers have non-overlapping features, the number of features (lines) in the resulting merged table should in principle equal the number of features in layer1 + the number of features in layer2;  *no features will be merged*, i.e., no new information will be added to any line (other than 'Null' values in new columns).

As far as I can tell, I'm not looking for any type of table join (my attempt at 'join by attribute' seems not to include all features from both layers) but rather a type of shapefile merge that gives me options as far as attributes go.  I could perhaps just rename all of the headers and that might give me what I'm hoping for, but I was looking for a more systematic way if that exists.

Comment: I recommend using legal column names (leading alpha), but otherwise this seems a simple Append operation.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment Vince; could you clarify what you mean by leading alpha?  As for Append, I assume you are referring to writing code as I do not think there is a QGIS function for this? I am getting started with Python, but am definitely not competent enough to write anything yet and this seems like a common enough need that there would be a function for it.

Comment: The dBase spec requires fieldnames to have an initial A-Z character (underscore and numeric are permitted in positions 2-10). ArcGIS has an Append, and so does QGIS (-ish) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131041/is-there-a-qgis-alternative-for-arcmaps-append-to-shapefile-data-management-t

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Merge vector layers`: this gives you a new vector layer with all features from all inputs layer and with all attributes separateley, containing `NULL` for attributes that did not exist in the layer the feature orginiates from.
2. Run `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`: it allows you the define in detail which attributes should be combined. You can use QGIS expressions, define an aggregate fucntion (like `sum` for adding values) and you might even change field data type.

*Screenshot: I combine two layers, `poly1` with an attribute `value1` and `poly2` with an attribute `poly2`. In the Aggregate dialog, I define that if the field for `poly1` is empty, the content of `value2` should be taken:*
[image]

Comment: Good trick.  I've never used Aggregate but now I surely will.  Thanks!